# Data Listing with Ajax (Only Last Data Coming) [SOLVED]

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am developing a project with ASP.NET Core. I want to pull data from the database with Ajax without posting the page. But only one and the last saved data comes. I can see other data in the console.

Can you help me?
Thanks,

```
<tr>
    <td class="border-bottom-0">
        <p id="getTaskTitle" class="fw-semibold mb-1l"></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
$("#btnGetTask").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                url: "/TaskList/ListTask/",
                success: function (func) {
                    let getList = jQuery.parseJSON(func);
                    let _getTaskTitle = document.getElementById("getTaskTitle")
                    $.each(getList, (i, value) => {
                        _getTaskTitle.innerText = `${value.TaskTitle}`
                        console.log(value.TaskTitle);
                    });

                }
            });
        });
```

It does not return any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop replace the value of inner text with recent value, so why it's show only last value.

Instead of add `innerText` in each loop create string and append once.

Example:

```
var htm = "";
let _getTaskTitle = $("#getTaskTitle");
$.each(getList, (i, value) => {
  htm += `${value.TaskTitle}`
  //console.log(value.TaskTitle);
});
_getTaskTitle.text(htm); //or _getTaskTitle.html(htm)
```

Update: based upon comment for break line between ajax response.

```js
// Your data from ajax request. It's only sample data for example.
var getList = [{
    TaskTitle: "red",
    value: "#f00"
  },
  {
    TaskTitle: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
  },
  {
    TaskTitle: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
  }
];
var htm = "";
let _getTaskTitle = $("#getTaskTitle");
var dt = [];
$.each(getList, (i, value) => {
  dt.push(`${value.TaskTitle}`);
});
htm = dt.join("<br>");
_getTaskTitle.html(htm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="getTaskTitle"></div>
```

*Note: Don't miss match jQuery and JavaScript.*

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can get all the values.

I would also like to ask, it sorts the values side by side.
It has to be one below the other in the table.

Do you have a solution for this?
Thank you again for your support.

Comment: Push your `value.TaskTitle` in array and before append join  with `\n`. Example: `let a =['a', 'b']; var b = a.join("\n"); console.log(b);` for line break.

Comment: How should I adapt these codes?
When I try I get `join is not a function` warning.

I'm not very good at Ajax, sorry to trouble you.

Comment: @gkmnada Updated my answer for line break. See updated answer. Running fiddle works .